# How to add scroll function to Oracle APEX year selector in the datepicker?

Tags: oracle-apex

In the current version of Oracle APEX the year selector does not seem to have a scroll bar in order to view more dates. I was wondering how I am able to add this functionality? Would this JQuery code work? If so, I am not sure where I would add it in the Oracle APEX page. I put it in 'Execute when Page Loads' area but it still is not giving me a scroll bar.

```
$(function(){
    $(".apex-item-select-list[data-apex-type='YEAR']").each(function(){
        var yearList = $(this);
        yearList.on('click', function(){
            yearList.find('.apex-item-option').wrapAll('<div class="year-list-container" />');
            yearList.find('.year-list-container').css({ 'height': '200px', 'overflow-y': 'scroll' });
        });
    }); });
```

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it, but I'd greatly advise against doing this. You're trying to change the behaviour of a native apex component. Those can change every release, which means that twice a year - when the apex version upgrades, there is a risk that this breaks.